# Why do DVORs and CVORs rotate in different directions?

Tags: vor, radio-navigation

I am currently studying both systems and I have the following doubt: why does DVOR rotate counterclockwise as opossed to CVOR? Could it be because the reference and variable signal are "swapped" between both of them?

Comment: Basically yes. What matters is how the two signals are rotated relative to each other.

Comment: So in this case, I can not understand how the signals can rotate relative to each other only variating the rotating direction